# If No Radio Buttons Are Checked

Tags: html

I have the following radio buttons:

```html
<div id="radiobuttons" class="container" name="buttons" align=center>

  <h2>I Want my Building to be Made of:</h2>

  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1" onClick="choose('bricks')">
    <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3" onClick="choose('wood')">
    <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2" onClick="choose('stone')">
    <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>

    <div class="check">
      <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form action="chooseheight.html">
  <div class="wrapper">
<button class="button" onClick="changechanceoflive();test()" align=center>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the button, it will take them to the next page. Although, I don't want them to go onto the next page without checking one of the buttons. Help?

Comment: Isn't there a default option?

Comment: You can't do this in straight HTML (without checking one by default). You will need to use javascript. Add a check in your `changechanceoflive()` method.

Comment: align=center is deprecated, use style="text-align:center"

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 1) {
    alert('Please select at least one.');
    return false;
  }
  
  alert('Success');
  // document.forms['myform'].submit;
}
```

```html
<div id="radiobuttons" class="container" name="buttons" align=center>

  <h2>I Want my Building to be Made of:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1">
      <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3">
      <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2">
      <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form id="myform" action="chooseheight.html">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate();" />
  </div>
</form>
```